# Primefaces commandButton submitting on enter

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have two commandButtons and when I hit enter the first one submits.  I really only want to submit the second button if the user hits enter.  Any ideas?

Comment: If it is possible, you could change the type of the first button to `type="button"` or make it an ajax button (`p:commandButton` is by default an ajax button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to swap the position of those two buttons thats all.

Your current code should be.

```
<p:commandButton value="button1" action="#{bean.action1}"/>
<p:commandButton value="button2" action="#{bean.action2}"/>
```

By default the button1 action will be triggered. You can present the user an alternative view, by adding `style="float:right" to the button1.`

```
<p:commandButton value="button1" style="float: right" action="#{bean.action2}"/>
<p:commandButton value="button2" action="#{bean.action1}"/>
```

Using the above the button1 will appear after the button2, and perform the action of button2, whenever the Enter is pressed.

Comment: Hi selvin, this issue only happens in IE for me, but can be seen on http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogForm.jsf.  Do you know another way around this besides positioning?

Answer (score 7):

I realize that the question is old, but maybe it is still interessing for someone to see a different solution.

You can use the Primefaces defaultCommand and adding an id to your prefered Button to define what happens when the Enter key is pressed. That's all.

```
<p:commandButton value="button1" action="#{bean.action1}"/>
<p:commandButton value="button2" id="btn_to_enter" action="#{bean.action2}"/>
<p:defaultCommand target="btn_to_enter" />
```